# How to maintain MainActivity UI and state when returning from SettingsActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am building a weather app, and I'm having trouble with the "back" functionality from my Settings page.  As you can see in the gift below, I switch the city to New Orleans, and then open the settings page.  When I click the back button from the settings page, it goes back, but reloads the MainActivity, which sets the city to the user's default, as it would when they first open the application.  I would like for it to go back to the screen exactly as it was when the user opened the settings, without reloading the data.  The data is retrieved in onCreateView() of MasterFragment, which is the main weather screen shown here.

SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat and is in the xml of SettingsActivity, which is launched from MainActivity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

I do not have `onBackPressed()` implemented in SettingsActivity.

I've gone through several SO questions about back stacks, but none of them seem to work with the setup that I have.

[gif of current behavior](https://i.imgur.com/vbW5AtP.gifv)

Edit:
MainActivity.java (the activity_main.xml file is the container for the main weather fragment)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.jggdevelopment.simpleweather", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (prefs.getBoolean("useDarkTheme", false)) {
            setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme);
        } else {
            setTheme(R.style.LightTheme);
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Setup the content view
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        // This is a mostly blank activity, so MasterFragment needs to be pushed onto the content_frame
        MasterFragment master = new MasterFragment();
        pushToFragmentManager(getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.content_frame, master, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code of the first Activity. First guess is that you have code in `onStart` that does some refresh logic, which will get triggered each time the Activity is returned to.

Comment: Edited.  As far as I'm aware, I don't, but I'm also largely unfamiliar with the stack and cycle between activities like that.  I'm launching the fragment in the onCreate() of MainActivity, but I didn't think onCreate() would be called when going back to an activity like that, I thought it was onResume()

Comment: Sounds strange. When `SettingsActivity` returns, it should just call `finish()` and go away (this is the default implementation of `onBackPressed()`, and then the existing instance of `MainActivity`  should regain control in its current state. Have you got "up navigation" declared or implemented in `SettingsActivity`? That would explain the behaviour. In that case, `MainActivity` would be restarted". To check if that is the case, add logging to `MainActivity.onCreate()` that writes the contents of the `Intent` to the log. You should write especially the flags from the `Intent`.

Comment: It is strange, I've never dealt with this before.  Which intent do I need to be checking the contents of?  The one from `onNavigationItemSelected()` wouldn't be available in the `onCreate()` of `MainActivity`

Comment: I just found that when you're in the settings screen and use the system back button (in the nav bar, or with a gesture), everything works as expected.  But when you use the back button in the toolbar it doesn't.  I suspect the issue is within `onBackPressed()` in `MainActivity`, where it's finding the `DrawerLayout` again

Comment: If that is the extent of your Activity, next guess is the issue is in the MasterFragment. Post that.